# Ruby, replacing values in a string array with strings/ints

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to replace an array with a new array, replacing values as I go along.

Here's the code:

```
minesarray = [['*','.','.','.'],['.','.','*','.'],['.','.','.','.']]

def pp_board(board)
    puts Array.new(board[0].size*2+1, '-').join('')
    board.each do |row|
        puts "|" + row.join("|") + "|"
        puts Array.new(row.size*2+1, '-').join('')
    end
end

pp_board(minesarray)

count = 0

minesarray.map{ |row|
    row.each { |col|
        if minesarray[row][col] = '*'
            minesarray[row][col]="a"
        elif minesarray[row][col] = '.'
            minesarray[row][col] = 0
        end
    }
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
mines2.rb:17:in '[]': can't convert Array into Integer (TypeError)
   from mines2.rb:17:in 'block (2 levels) in (main)'
   from mines2.rb:16:in 'each'
   from mines2.rb:16:in 'block in (main)'
   from mines2.rb:15:in 'map'
   from mines2.rb:15:in '(main)'
```

Comment: Start with `elif` => `elsif`, and fix `if minesarray[row][col] = '*'`

Answer (score 2):

The `row` and `col` is not the index of the array, but the element itself.

You could do like below:

```
minesarray = [['*','.','.','.'],['.','.','*','.'],['.','.','.','.']]

def pp_board(board)
    puts Array.new(board[0].size*2+1, '-').join('')
    board.each do |row|
        puts "|" + row.join("|") + "|"
        puts Array.new(row.size*2+1, '-').join('')
    end
end

pp_board(minesarray)

minesarray = minesarray.map { |row|
  row.map { |v|
    if v == '*'
      'a'
    elsif v == '.'
      '0'
    end
  }
}

pp_board(minesarray)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `row` and `col` are not indexes, they are the actual elements of the array.

You also have a couple of other issues. "elif" should be `elsif` and you're using assignment (`=`) in your conditionals where you should be using an equality check (`==`).